# When using np.linalg.eigvals, I am getting the first eigenvalue with negative value systematically. Why is this?

Tags: python, numpy, math, statistics, algebra

I am working in a implementation of the Expectation-Maximization algorithm with Missing Data for Mixture of MVNs. You don't have to know anything about this algorithm to help me with my issue.

Let say that my dataset has shape `D x N` with `D = 6`.

I compute the estimation of sigma (the covariance matrix). The result is a `6 x 6` matrix (everything ok).

Then I have to compute the PDF of some samples for the distribution with the mean and covariance matrix that I just computed (estimated parameters).
In order to compute the PDF, I use `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal` because it has a pdf() method.

But I always get the following error:

```
ValueError: the input matrix must be positive semidefinite
```

This error is due to the covariance matrix. I have checked its eigenvalues, and the first eigenvalue is always a negative value.
Some real examples that I got:

```py
import numpy as np

eigvals = np.linalg.eigvals(sigma)  # shape (6,)

'''
Three different results that I got in different executions (the
parameters are randomly generated)

[-406.73080893   94.43623712   57.06170498   73.75668673   69.21443981
   70.60878445]
[-324.74509361  104.75315794   50.43203113   67.92014983   63.35285505
   65.41071698]
[-277.14957619   98.17501755   69.8623394    54.49958827   59.4808295
   57.28174734]
'''
```

**Does anyone know why this is happening?**

I am not very familiar with the eigenvalues, so I would greatly appreciate your help.

## ==================== MORE INFO ====================

Here I include some code of how I compute sigma:

```py
# This is how I compute the covariance matrix
def estimate_sigma_with_nan(xx_est, gamma_k, mu):
    sigma = (xx_est / gamma_k) - np.dot(mu, np.transpose(mu))
    return sigma  # = (d, d)

# This is how I compute xx_est. I will include a image of the maths behind this
exp_prod = np.zeros_like(xx_est_k)
x_i_norm[m] = estimate_x_norm(x_i_norm, mu_k, sigma_k, m, o)
exp_prod[np.ix_(m, m)] = estimate_xx_norm(reshape_(x[:d, i], keep_axes=range(2)), mu_k, sigma_k, m, o)
exp_prod[np.ix_(o, o)] = np.dot(x_i_norm[o], np.transpose(x_i_norm[o]))
exp_prod[np.ix_(o, m)] = np.dot(x_i_norm[o], np.transpose(x_i_norm[m]))
exp_prod[np.ix_(m, o)] = np.dot(x_i_norm[m], np.transpose(x_i_norm[o]))
xx_est = xx_est + (exp_prod * gamma[k, i])

def estimate_xx_norm(x_i, mu_k, sigma_k, m, o):
    assert x_i.ndim == 2 and mu_k.ndim == 2 and sigma_k.ndim == 2
    est_xx = sigma_k[np.ix_(m, m)] - np.dot(np.dot(sigma_k[np.ix_(m, o)], np.linalg.inv(sigma_k[np.ix_(o, o)])), np.transpose(sigma_k[np.ix_(m, o)]))
    est_xx = est_xx + np.dot(estimate_x_norm(x_i, mu_k, sigma_k, m, o), np.transpose(estimate_x_norm(x_i, mu_k, sigma_k, m, o)))
    assert est_xx.ndim == 2
    return est_xx
```

This work is based on [this paper](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/nips93.pdf):

[image]

Comment: This might be a topic for http://stats.stackexchange.com, as this is more about validating your source and if that was faithfully translated into code. No covariance matrix should have negative eigenvalues, they are by construction positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way covariance matrix is computed is wrong.
If X is (N, m) matrix with N as sample size and m as feature size,
then

```py
conv = (X - X_mean).T.dot((X - X_mean)) / (X.shape[0] - 1)
```

`(X.shape[0] - 1)` is becuase this is samples

Comment: yes, you could be right... I did that because I saw it in [another implementation](https://github.com/probml/pmtk3/blob/master/toolbox/LatentVariableModels/mixGauss/mixGaussMissingFitEm.m). If you look at `lines 97-109` in the file of the link, don't they do the same as I am doing? I think so... but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: also, why it should be `(X.shape[0] - 1)`? I don't see why I should use that instead of `X.shape[0]`

Comment: actually I realized that you are wrong, because I am already subtracting the mean in the `estimate_sigma_with_nan` function, and I don't have to divide by `X.shape[0]` because I am already doing this when I divide by `gamma_k` in the same function.

Comment: First of all, use `(X.shape[0] - 1)` is because it is sample convarance matrix due to the bias of the sample. On the other side, no idea why you use `sigma = (xx_est / gamma_k) - np.dot(mu, np.transpose(mu))`, because I didn't find it in your link